# CSV file output not well aligned with "read.csv()"

Tags: r, csv, output

I run the "R code" in "RKWard" to read a CSV file:

```
# I) Go to the working directory
setwd("/home/***/Desktop/***")

# II) Verify the current working directory
print(getwd())

# III) Load te nedded package
require("csv")

# IV) Read the desired file
read.csv(file="CSV_Example.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";")
```

The data in CSV file is as follow (an example token from this website):

```
id,name,salary,start_date,dept
1,Rick,623.3,2012-01-01,IT
2,Dan,515.2,2013-09-23,Operations
3,Michelle,611,2014-11-15,IT
4,Ryan,729,2014-05-11,HR
5,Gary,843.25,2015-03-27,Finance
6,Nina,578,2013-05-21,IT
7,Simon,632.8,2013-07-30,Operations
8,Guru,722.5,2014-06-17,Finance
```

But the result is as follow:

```
       id.name.salary.start_date.dept
1          1,Rick,623.3,2012-01-01,IT
2   2,Dan,515.2,2013-09-23,Operations
3        3,Michelle,611,2014-11-15,IT
4            4,Ryan,729,2014-05-11,HR
5    5,Gary,843.25,2015-03-27,Finance
6            6,Nina,578,2013-05-21,IT
7 7,Simon,632.8,2013-07-30,Operations
8    8,Guru,722.5,2014-06-17,Finance
```

PROBLEM: The datas **are not aligned** as supposed to be.
Please can anyone help me

Comment: in your step IV, change sep=";" to `sep=","`

Comment: Thanks you it works, but please can you explain the mistake?

Comment: The sep argument specifies the delimiter used to separate columns. Your file was comma separated not semi colon separated

Comment: In **step IV** I tried this script to select the **mean of salary**: `mean(read.csv(file="CSV_Example.csv", header=TRUE, sep="|")["salary"])` But I didn't get the desired result